# Is there a "right" way to release all resources once you are done doing openCL processing?

Tags: resources, release, opencl

I guess the simple way is to restart the program, but is there a way to get the same effect without closing the program? I call the proper release statements for my allocated memory, my context, and command queue, but I never trust that any openCL call actually does what I want when I call it.

For example, the call for creating a buffer doesn't actually create the buffer until I read from it.

I am curious if there is a way to force cleanup or something similar. Let me know, thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? What sort of extra cleanup do you think could be done after you've released/deallocated everything? Also, what platform are you talking about? There isn't likely to be a portable way to force more cleanup than what the CL spec gives you the tools for.

Answer (score 4):

No, the OpenCL spec only defines clRelease* functions to do that. Besides, there is no extra cleanup you need to do, just that OpenCL objects are reference counted, so they are only deleted when they reference count reaches 0.

I don't know Why you don't trust OpenCL to do what it says it will do. Some implementations are a bit buggy, but that should be fixed as OpenCL implementations mature.

Comment: Exactly, the behaviour of the buffer creation is part of the implementation, but releasing a handle is explicitly defined.